# allow user to update only one field

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

is there a simple way to allow the update of a single field of the document without comparing all the document fields ?

Answer (score 0):

You can check what fields are affected by a write operation, and then restrict based on that. From the notes when [map diffs](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/security-rules#february_13_2020) were introduced:

```js
// This rule only allows updates where "a" is the only field affected
allow update: if request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["a"]);
```